# How to correctly set Mock Row and Query for go-sqlmock

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, go, go-gin, go-sqlmock

I'm setting up testing in `golang`.
I use `go-sqlmock` to test mysql connection.
But `sqlmock.NewRows` and `mock.ExpectQuery` does not work well with error.
I want to know how to resolve this error.

```
server side: golang
db: mysql
web framework: gin
```

dao.go

```golang
func GetSingleArticleDao(c *gin.Context, db *sql.DB) (util.Article, *sql.Rows) {
    id := c.Params.ByName("id")
    article := util.Article{}
    errArticle := db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = ?", id).Scan(&article.ID, &article.UUID, &article.TITLE, &article.CONTENT)
    if errArticle != nil {
        panic(errArticle.Error())
    }
    rows, errImage := db.Query("SELECT image_name FROM images WHERE article_uuid  = ?", article.UUID)
    if errImage != nil {
        panic(errImage.Error())
    }

    return article, rows
}
```

dao_test.go

```golang
func TestGetSingleArticleDao(t *testing.T) {
    db, mock, err := sqlmock.New()

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("an error '%s' was not expected when opening a stub database connection", err)
    }

    defer db.Close()

    articleMockRows := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"id", "uuid", "title", "content"}).
        AddRow("1", "bea1b24d-0627-4ea0-aa2b-8af4c6c2a41c", "test", "test")

    mock.ExpectQuery("SELECT (.+) FROM articles where id=\\?").
        WithArgs("1").
        WillReturnRows(articleMockRows)

    imageMockRows := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"article_uuid", "image_name"}).
        AddRow("bea1b24d-0627-4ea0-aa2b-8af4c6c2a41c", "1a90696f-4fe7-48f5-81a5-ca72c129f4b0").
        AddRow("bea1b24d-0627-4ea0-aa2b-8af4c6c2a41c", "3d997272-468f-4b66-91db-00c39f0ef717")

    mock.ExpectQuery("^SELECT (.+) FROM images*").
        WithArgs("bea1b24d-0627-4ea0-aa2b-8af4c6c2a41c").
        WillReturnRows(imageMockRows)

    resp := httptest.NewRecorder()
    gin.SetMode(gin.TestMode)
    ctx, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(resp)

    article, imageRows := GetSingleArticleDao(ctx, db)

    for imageRows.Next() {
        imageName := util.ImageName{}
        err := imageRows.Scan(&imageName.NAME)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
        article.IMAGENAMES = append(article.IMAGENAMES, imageName)
    }

    expectedArticle := util.Article{
        ID:      1,
        UUID:    "bea1b24d-0627-4ea0-aa2b-8af4c6c2a41c",
        TITLE:   "test",
        CONTENT: "test",
    }

    imageName1 := util.ImageName{
        NAME: "1a90696f-4fe7-48f5-81a5-ca72c129f4b0",
    }
    expectedArticle.IMAGENAMES = append(expectedArticle.IMAGENAMES, imageName1)

    imageName2 := util.ImageName{
        NAME: "3d997272-468f-4b66-91db-00c39f0ef717",
    }

    expectedArticle.IMAGENAMES = append(expectedArticle.IMAGENAMES, imageName2)

    assert.Equal(t, expectedArticle, article)
}
```

I expect `go test -v` runs without error.
But the actual is not.
Here is the error.

```
$ go test -v 
=== RUN   TestGetSingleArticleDao
--- FAIL: TestGetSingleArticleDao (0.00s)
panic: Query: could not match actual sql: "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = ?" with expected regexp "SELECT (.+) FROM articles where id=\?" [recovered]
        panic: Query: could not match actual sql: "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = ?" with expected regexp "SELECT (.+) FROM articles where id=\?"

goroutine 34 [running]:
testing.tRunner.func1(0xc00022c000)
        /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:830 +0x392
panic(0x165a960, 0xc0001bc4a0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:522 +0x1b5
article/api/dao.GetSingleArticleDao(0xc000214160, 0xc0002180c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        /Users/jpskgc/article/api/dao/dao.go:26 +0x35d
article/api/dao.TestGetSingleArticleDao(0xc00022c000)
        /Users/jpskgc/article/api/dao/dao_test.go:92 +0x750
testing.tRunner(0xc00022c000, 0x1788730)
        /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:865 +0xc0
created by testing.(*T).Run
        /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:916 +0x35a
exit status 2
FAIL    article/api/dao 0.030s
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use `regexp.QuoteMeta()` to escape all regular expression metacharacters in your query instead of using `\\`:

```
mock.ExpectQuery(regexp.QuoteMeta("SELECT (.+) FROM articles FROM articles WHERE id = ?")).
            WithArgs("1").
            WillReturnRows(articleMockRows)
```

Just a little tips, instead of doing it like this:

```
mock.ExpectQuery("SELECT (.+) FROM articles where id=\\?").
        WithArgs("1").
        WillReturnRows(articleMockRows)
```

You can try it by doing it like this:

```
mock.ExpectQuery("SELECT (.+) FROM articles").
        WithArgs("1").
        WillReturnRows(articleMockRows)
```

It depends on what you want to check in your query, but for me, the most important thing is to check whether my query selects the correct table or not. I mostly do not care which property is used to filter the data.
If you think the filter is important, then, there are also some more examples here:

- https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock/blob/master/sqlmock_test.go
- https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock/blob/master/sqlmock_go18_test.go
- https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/data-dog/go-sqlmock#example-package

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by following part

```golang
    resp := httptest.NewRecorder()
    gin.SetMode(gin.TestMode)
    ctx, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(resp)
```

I should add `"id" :"1"` param in ctx.
So I changed that part into this:

```
    param := gin.Param{"id", "1"}
    params := gin.Params{param}
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/article/1", nil)
    var context *gin.Context
    context = &gin.Context{Request: req, Params: params}
```